# How to Persist Rows after Reordering p:dataTable rows in backing bean

Tags: primefaces

I am using Primefaces Datatable to show the data, i have used draggablerows and trying to save/persist the reordering of the rows in the backing bean

with

I can get the from and to indexes from the event. But, I was not able to persist the row reordering:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{EmployeeHandler.model.employees}" var="employee"  draggableRows="true"> 

<p:ajax event="rowReorder" listener="#{EmployeeHandler.onRowReorder}"/>

<p:column>
<h:outputText value="#{employee.id}"/
</p:column>
<p:column>
<h:outputText value="#{employee.firstName}"/
</p:column>

<p:column>
<h:outputText value="#{employee.lastName}"/
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

I tried

```
   public void onRowReorder(ReorderEvent event) {

   List<Employee> employees = model.getEmployees (new order in the  employees list); 
   fromIndex = event.getFromIndex();
   toIndex = event.getToIndex();

   // swapping indexes  
   Collections.swap(employees, fromIndex, toIndex); 

   }
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? Actual persistence or setting the new index on a record?  The former is not jsf related, the latter plain java (assuming you have the current records in a list). So I fail to see your actual coding problem.

Comment: The problem is to set the new index on a record. Yes it is related to java, I want to save the new order of the rows in the list.

Comment: @Kukeltje edited the question, can you please suggest

Comment: Your *'I tried'*, contains effectively no code. And if it is pure java, start with a plain java class with an array, create some sort of fake event handler to switch an elements' position in the array. How would you do that. Do the same here... You have to so some plain coding here. Nothing JSF or PrimeFaces. In the reoder event you have the old and new index (as you showed in the code previous to your edit.

Comment: @Kukeltje Is this the correct solution

Comment: Answers should be in answers and not in the question ;-). But effectively your are changing them in the list now. That might be part of it, but you most likely also need to update some field in the record. And I think I would not swap the variables, but actual indices in the list

Comment: @Kukeltje: Unfortunately I can't post in Answers section: I edited the tried section

Comment: You can't post annswer on your own question?

Comment: The swap in java is totally different than what you do in the datatable. You don't swap two records there, you move one record from a certain index to a new on ( changing ALL in between... )